# Turtlebot2 does not move in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

So according to this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world

All I need to do to tele-op the turtlebot2 in gazebo is:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

However when I do this, the turtlebot does not move.  I have also tried running:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

and creating a python node to move it, all to no avail.  What am I missing?

Thank you to bit-pirate for catching my missing specs:
Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro, i used sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot* to get the packages.

EDIT: My Turtlebot2 simulation IS MOVING, however it is moving so slow that you can't even see it move unless you leave Gazebo running for a while and come back to it.  How can I make Gazebo run faster?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99276/turtlebot2-does-not-move-in-gazebo/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-11-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-09**:
I am thinking of using turtlebot on Gazebo. As I am new to Gazebo; initially I thought that for turtlebot 2D navigation stack is already set up and we can control everything from rviz.

Does we need to write code for moving the turtlebot?
Do you know any robot in Gazebo-Ros for which 2D navigation stack is already tuned properly?

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-09**:
Hi Brian, the navigation stack does already have a lot of utilities for using the turtlebot, the only one I know of that uses rviz though is the goal waypoints you can set while using amcl.  I am writing code to move it simply because my application requires it.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-09**:
Hi, my requirement is also similar to you, but right now I need a robot upon which 2D navigation stack properly set up. I am planning to incorporate my own code inside amcl. As you have said for TurtleBot, we can use 2D nav stack; does this robot can be properly launched in Gazeb? Does turtleBot can avail all the functionality of 2D nav stack.? Thanks 4 ur reply.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-10**:
@Robocop87 The instructions on the wiki work out of the box for me - no need to create nor run extra nodes. Please specific more details about your setup (what and how did you install the turtlebot packages, what versions are you using (Ubuntu, ROS, turtlebot packages)).

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-10**:
Added the specs, thanks for the catch.  Still doesn't work for me though =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all you should **not** use `turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch`. That launcher is for running the real robot. The Gazebo plugins for TurtleBot are basically reproducing the same functionalities (not everything is implemented though).

What does Gazebo's real time factor say? Maybe the simulation is running really slowly on your machine (my "Real Time Factor" is at 1.0).

Note that turtlebot_teleop's keyboard_teleop requires you to keep the buttons pressed. Please also try `roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-10**:
Thanks for your answer bit-pirate, I have since stopped attempting to run turtlebot_bringup as I realized it was causing nodes to crash in Gazebo.  My real time factor says 1.0

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-10**:
Odd... Please add the version numbers of Gazebo and the turtlebot, turtlebot_apps, turtlebot_simulator, kobuki and kobuki_desktop packages to your question.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-10**:
Gazebo: 2.0.0
Turtlebot: 2.2.2
Turtlebot_apps: 2.2.4
Turtlebot_simulator: 2.1.1
Kobuki: 0.5.5
Kobuki_desktop: 0.3.1

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-10**:
Gazebo 2.0! That might be it. I tested version 2.0 after the release and ran into some problems. So far no one got around implementing the necessary changes. Please revert back to Gazebo 1.9.1. and do try teleop again.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-15**:
Could this possibly have any connection with my graphics card? I imagine it moving too slow could mean its not good enough?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-17**:
If your real time factor is at 1.0, it should be fine. If the simulation time would pass much slower than real time, then there would probably be too much load on your system. Did you test the turtlebot simulation with Gazebo 1.9?

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-12-07**:
No I never did, I never figured out how to revert the version and I ended up just using another computer...sorry!